# How to load config file without any file extension in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to figure out option to load config file in SpringBoot app which doesn't have any file extension.

e.g. I have 2 config files application.properties and secrets that I mention using external location. Spring ignores **secrets** config file; however, when I change **secrets** file extension to properties/yml it works.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local \
-Dspring.config.location=file:///<config location>/git/graphql-account/secrets,file:///<config location>/git/graphql-account/application-local.properties
```

I have explored [Spring guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) but couldn't find solution for this. 
Any suggestions how to resolve this issue?

Note: I am using openshift cloud and I need to load it's secrets which are available in **/opt/epaas/vault/secrets/secrets** . I am not allowed to change file extension.

Comment: why not naming it as `secrets.properties` or `secrets.yml` ?

Comment: I am using openshift cloud and I need to load it's secrets from location- /opt/epaas/vault/secrets/secrets . I am not allowed to change file extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution could be using `@PropertySource` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("file:/etc/secrets")
public class Demo {

   public static void main(...) {...}
}
```

`/etc/secrets` is a regular properties file (key/value pairs but without extension).

Of course, if you want to configure the place of `/etc/secrets` you can use SPEL in `@PropertySource` annotation attribute definition:

```
@PropertySource(value="file:/${secrets.file.localtion}"
```